# How to get all the Test Executed from Zephyr JIRA API for Multiple Cycle IDs in One Shot

Tags: jira-rest-api, jira-zephyr

Is there any way to get all the test case executed details from the multiple test cycles at a time

Currently i have some 3 Cycle IDs but I am making 3 GET API calls to get from each cycle

```
https://<JIRA HOST>/rest/zapi/latest/execution?projectId=<Project ID>&versionId=<Version ID>&cycleId=<Cycle ID 1>
https://<JIRA HOST>/rest/zapi/latest/execution?projectId=<Project ID>&versionId=<Version ID>&cycleId=<Cycle ID 2>
https://<JIRA HOST>/rest/zapi/latest/execution?projectId=<Project ID>&versionId=<Version ID>&cycleId=<Cycle ID 3>
```

Is there anyway I get all the details in one shot for Cycle ID 1 & 2 & 3

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get execution results for multiple test cycles using Zephyr ExecutionSearchResource API and ZQL query.

Use this:
https://JIRA_HOST/restrest/zapi/latest/zql/executeSearch?zqlQuery=project="ProjectName" AND fixVersion="VersionName" AND cycleName IN ("CycleName1", "CycleName2", "Cyclename3")

The above URL facilitates to query for multiple projects or versions as well.

Reference: http://docs.getzephyr.apiary.io/#

Thanks :)

Anuj.

Comment: is there any way I can restrict few fields from the Response, I dont want to get all the fields and I just want to know `executedOn`, How I can achieve this